# NSView free-angle rotation

Tags: macos, rotation, nsview

I have `NSView` container (with NSImageView and some other custom subviews). How to set its rotation properly? I tried to set angle through `setFrameRotation:` and set rotation matrix in views layer. But in these cases subview image becomes downscaled and clipped.

Update:

If I set rotation via `[myView setFrameRotation: angle]`:

[image]

- almost fine, except text frame (drawing via `[NSString drawAtPoint:...]` and rotation anchor is at left-bottom corner (I want at bottom-center, `[myView setFrameOrigin:...]` does nothing)

If I set rotation via `myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (angle, 0, 0, 1)`:

[image]

- frame bound remains unrotated and clips subviews (but this approach is more suitable for view container)

Comment: Can you please share the snippet of code you're using, and/or a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing?